# leave program running in the background and continuously check on the value of the clock

Tags: python, loops

My goal is to create a program which continuously checks on the value of time,compares it to variable values (static for now: one or two or three), it will open a specific page, if it matches the value one, I still want the program to stay running till it matches two, perform the same action, same for the value of three.

1- How do I let my program run continuously **while checking the clock value** ?

2- How do I let the program alive to run for the second and third value ?

The program only works when I run it specifically at the exact time of one of the values...

```
import time
import webbrowser
print(" This started on " + time.strftime("%H:%M"))
count = 0
clock = time.strftime("%H:%M")
#values i want to assign for breaks
one = "17:15"
two = "21:15"
three = "23:00"
#continous loop
while True:
   if (clock == one ):
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZbuj3RJcjI")
    break
elif (clock == two):
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZbuj3RJcjI")
    break
elif (clock == three):
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZbuj3RJcjI")
    break
else:
    print "finished"
break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- How do I let my program run continuously while checking the clock value ?

-- Reassign the clock variables value within the while loop, this will keep checking against the updated timestamp

2- How do I let the program alive to run for the second and third value ?

-- Don't break out of your loop. Continue running

```
import time
import webbrowser

print(" This started on " + time.strftime("%H:%M"))

#values i want to assign for breaks
times = ["17:15", "21:15", "23:00"]

#continous loop
while True:
    clock = time.strftime("%H:%M")

    if clock in times:
        webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZbuj3RJcjI")

    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Thanks Alan! 
However, I tried to run the code with the modifications you recommended, using a list and the below code, it causes my whole computer to crash (using linux ubuntu).

Comment: Nevermind I had to increase the time.sleep(60), since it the loop was consistently running when the clock matches, meaning opening infinite videos during that specific minute, hence crashing my computer :D Thanks Alan!

Comment: Yes, sorry - you can also remove the continue statement (this jumps to the next iteration of the loop meaning the sleep wont run) -- see updated code

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the **break** statement and the **else** block, then it won't break the **while** block.

Comment: Hi Oscar, I've only added the last break for testing. If the loop continuously runs, there is no way that the program would work, unless if the value of the clock is continuously checked if it matches the one,two,three values...th program would run but not work..

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a pub-sub implementation?

When your time matches, emit a signal. Have other processes subscribe, and listen for that signal. Pseudocoded:

```
if (time == 1) {
    emit "ONE"
} else if (time == 2) 
    emit "TWO"
} else {
    emit "THREE"
}
```

Subscriber(s):

```
void (ONE_emitted) {
    //do something
}
void (TWO_emitted) {
    //do something else
}
void (THREE_emitted) {
    //do a different thing
}
```

Have processes subscribe to these broadcasted events, and do whatever you want with them.

This will also keep your "page opening" process separate from your "time checking" process(es).

The emitting program will continue to run.

I'm not so much a Python guy, but here's more on the pub-sub model in Python:
http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/v3.1/apidocs/examples.html

Comment: Thank You! I'm also quite a beginner in python I'll have to check how to relate the API to the program

Comment: The concept with pub-sub is that the events are loosely coupled with actions. An analogy would be subscribing to receive push notifications for weather, sports, and financial news. The push notification is the PUBlication part. You get it because you SUBscribed. If you get a sport notification, what you do with that piece of information does not affect the publisher. It seems perfect for your task.